# Update a field of a content entry in Locomotivecms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, locomotivecms

In Locomotivecms,I created a content type called "posts" with a field called "views" which is integer. The field "views" are supposed to add 1 incrementally every time the content entry page was visited. 
I try {% assign post.views = post.views +1 %} in liquid ,but that didn't make sense. 
Is there any liquid tag to carry it out ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try `{% increment post.views %}`

Answer (score 0):

You can increment in Locomotive CMS this way:

```
{% assign counter = 0 %}
{% capture counter %}{{ counter | plus: 1 }}{% endcapture %}
```